# Event listener (on click, link to show page) only working once in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Noob here. I have an `index.html.erb` file that lists clients from my database in a table format and each row within the table is clickable as a link to each client's respective show page. The only problem is that although my attached event listener works, it is only working once. If I navigate back to my index page, I cannot click on the client index table rows anymore. I followed a YouTube tutorial to get this far. I trimmed my code down to what I think is relevant. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I want to emphasize that **this is within an HTML table, talking about clicking on HTML table rows**. This means ordinary `<a>` tags and ERB `link_to` are not options.

```
      <tbody>
        <% @clients.each do |client| %>
          <tr data-href="<%= client_path(client) %>" class="odd:bg-white even:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer hover:bg-indigo-300 hover:ring-blue-700 hover:ring-inset">
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
              <%= client.first_name + " " + client.last_name %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-href]");

      rows.forEach(row => {
          row.addEventListener("click", () => {
              window.location.href = row.dataset.href;
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need JS to to go to client page? Or is it a poop?

Comment: It's a table row within a table which means I can't use <a> tags or link_to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's a conflict with Turbolinks which is enabled on new Rails projects by default (for now). Try replacing `window.location.href = row.dataset.href` with `Turbolinks.visit(row.dataset.href)`

The [Turbolinks docs](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/blob/master/README.md#triggering-a-turbolinks-visit-manually) have more info on this.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still behaving the same way after replacing my code with yours. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I will post my answer when I figure it out.

Comment: The last piece of the puzzle was to replace `DOMContentLoaded` in the event listener to `turbolinks:load`. After replacing that it works perfectly. Thanks!